# Engineering Mathematics Problem with Taylor's Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, physics

This is a problem from Engineering Mathematics book by K. A. Stroud, 7th edition, Exercise 18, Chapter 12 Further problems. It has been given in a physics manner, but it just requires manipulation of Taylor series to get the result, which is what I can’t figure out. It doesn’t require any physics knowledge really to find the answer, that’s why I posted it on M.S.E. It states:

> The field strength of a magnet $(H)$ at a point on the axis, distance $x$ from its center, is given by:
> $$H=\frac{M}{2l}\left(\frac{1}{(x-l)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+l)^2}\right),$$
> where $2l =$ length of magnet and $M =$ moment. Show that if $l$ is very small compared with $x$, then $ H \approx \frac{2M}{x^3} $.

As far as I’m concerned, $H$ is a fraction of $x$ there (but I’m not sure, maybe it’s $H(x,l)$?), so this is $H(x)$. And so i have to find the Taylor series representation of $H(x+l)$. What I get is this:
$$H(x+l) = \frac{M}{2l}\left(\frac{1}{(x-l)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+l)^2}\right) + M\left(\frac{1}{(x+l)^3}-\frac{1}{(x-l)^3}\right) + \frac{3Ml}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(x-l)^4}-\frac{1}{(x+l)^4}\right)$$
(since it says $l$ is small, I took only terms until the $x^2$ only).

I really don’t know how to prove what is needed in this. I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to expand it in terms of $\frac lx$?

Comment: hmm no.. Just to apply the taylor's series expansion (i think): $$ f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x)  + \frac{h^2}{2!}f''(x) + \frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x) + ... $$ until the $h^{2}$ term. In general I'm unsure of how to prove what is need here, but i think i need Taylor's series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use Taylor series, just algebra and limits:
$$H=\frac{M}{2l}\left(\frac{1}{(x-l)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+l)^2} \right)
=\frac{M}{2l}\frac{(x+l)^2-(x-l)^2}{(x^2-l^2)^2}
=\frac{M}{2l}\frac{4xl}{x^4(1-(l/x)^2)^2}
\approx \frac{2M}{x^3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

By the Taylor series expansion near $0$, say for $|u|<1$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}=1+2u+O(u^3) \tag1
$$$$
\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}=1-2u+O(u^3) \tag2
$$ giving
$$
\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}=4u+O(u^3) \tag3
$$ then, setting $u:=\dfrac{l}x$, we get from $(3)$, 
$$
\frac{M}{2l}\left\{\frac{1}{(x-l)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+l)^2}\right\}=\frac{M}{2lx^2}\left\{\frac{1}{(1-l/x)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+l/x)^2}\right\}=\frac{M}{2lx^2}\times \left(4\frac{l}x+O(l/x)^3\right)
$$ or

> $$ H=\color{blue}{\frac{2M}{x^3}}+O\left(\frac{l^2}{x^5}\right). \tag4$$

Comment: The binomial series have quadratic terms $+3u^2$ in both cases. They cancel in the next step, but as stated it is wrong.